# Why does cutoff voltage in photoelectric graph remain same regardless of change of intensity and frequency of light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photoelectric-effect, intensity

Why does cutoff voltage in photoelectric graph remain same regardless of change of intensity and frequency of light I understand in intensity that minimum voltage required to kick off slowest electron is constant as intensity is not related to energy of phtoelectron but cannot understand in case of frequency. I have attached a picture of the graphs:
[image: these are the two graphs of increasing intensity and frequency]

Comment: see this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html#c2

Answer (score 1):

Cut-off voltage in the photoelectric effect is a **characteristic of the material** and is in no way dependent on the intensity or frequency of light shown on the material. Why? Because cutoff voltage represents the amount of energy needed to knock-off the electrons from an atom and why would that change if you change the frequency or intensity of the incident light. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it really helps